# How do I reset pre-posed model to standard T pose, when parenting re-applies the same pose again?

Tags: pose-mode

I'm having trouble posing my model after opening it up after a while, it looks fine until I try and pose it, then the mesh doesn't move with the armature.

No problem, right? Just parent the mesh to the armature!

Nope, [image: Model messed up with re-applied pose] the model gets all screwed up, as blender tries to re-apply the already posed pose to the mesh a second time.

Also, resetting the pose before parenting, results in the armature to be in the t-pose, while the mesh remains posed.

How do I stop this from happening?

Comment: Have you applied the location to the armature? It looks like there is an offset caused by different origins. The yellow dot and the red dot should both be at the 3D Cursor which is at the world origin.

Comment: Applying the location doesn't seem to affect the parenting outcome